# Synchronization of writing to shared memory (list) in Python multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, shared-memory, python-multiprocessing, multiprocessing-manager

I have the following code:

```
import multiprocessing
manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
```

Function that appends list if it's length is less than 4 or creates a new one with initial value 'y'.

```
def f(my_array):
    if len(my_array) < 4:
        my_array.append('x')
    else:
        my_array = ['y']
    print(my_array)
```

Initialization of list and creating processes.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_array = manager.list(['a', 'b', 'c'])

    p1 = Process(target=f, args=(my_array))
    p2 = Process(target=f, args=(my_array))
    p3 = Process(target=f, args=(my_array))
    p4 = Process(target=f, args=(my_array))
    p5 = Process(target=f, args=(my_array))

    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p3.start()
    p4.start()
    p5.start()

    p1.join()
    p2.join()
    p3.join()
    p4.join()
    p5.join()
```

Output I got:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'x']
['y']
['y']
['y'] 
['y']
```

I don't understand why the list is appended only once. I expected that in the third output line I will observe list ['y'] appended by 'x', so ['y', 'x'], the fourth one ['y', 'x', 'x'] and so on. It seems like shared memory is leaky or does not permit to make a change by functions from multiple processes. What can I do to enable the targeted behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Synchronization is one point missing in your example. `manager.list` is just a normal `list` in a separate server-process which your worker-processes can modify through proxy-objects. Your further processes happen to check `len(my_array)` at the same time.

There is no synchronization, which tells them they should wait until another process has finished it's operation consisting of doing this length-check and performing an action dependent on the result of this check. Your updating operation is not an atomic operation, you need to make it one by using a manager.lock around your operation.

There's another problem in your code, where you re-bind `my_array` to point to a normal list `['y']`, instead of updating / modifying the shared `manager.list`. You are not modifying the `manager.list` with processes which set `my_array = ['y']`, the `manager.list` keeps it's value `['a', 'b', 'c', 'x']` from the first modification through the first worker-process till the end of your program.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager


def f(my_array, lock):
    with lock:
        if len(my_array) < 4:
            my_array.append('x')
        else:
            my_array[:] = []  # clear list inplace by assigning
            # empty list to slice of manager.list
            my_array.append('y')
    print(my_array)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    N_WORKERS = 5

    with Manager() as manager:

        my_array = manager.list(['a', 'b', 'c'])
        lock = manager.Lock()

        pool = [
            Process(target=f, args=(my_array, lock)) for _ in range(N_WORKERS)
        ]

        for p in pool:
            p.start()
        for p in pool:
            p.join()

        # Leaving the context-manager block will shut down the manager-process.
        # We need to convert the manager-list to a normal list in the parent
        # to keep its values available for further processing in the parent.
        result = list(my_array)

    print(f'result: {result}')
```

Example Output:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'x']
['y']
['y', 'x']
['y', 'x', 'x']
['y', 'x', 'x', 'x']
result: ['y', 'x', 'x', 'x']

Process finished with exit code 0
```